# Limited to one client/Connection

Tags: wcf, silverlight, iis

I have spent 2 days looking for a solution for this issue. It seems that calling WCF within a SilverLight Application is currently limited to only 1 client while it's working perfectly with a Console Application consuming WCF.

For now the issue is not clear and I don't even know which method have to follow.

**Environment**

OS : Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise, Silver Light 4, C# 4, IIS : 7.5

**Application Architecture**

- WCF Services hosted by Console Application

  ```
  [OperationContract]
  string DoConnect(int id, string who);
  ```
- Silver Light Application referring/calling WCF in Asynchronous way on press button hosted by IIS.

  ```
  private void MultipleConnection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e1)
  {
      WCFServicesX3Ref.WCFServicesX3Client client = new WCFServicesX3Ref.WCFServicesX3Client();
      client.DoConnectCompleted += (s,e) =>
      {
          if (e.Result == null){ MessageBox.Show("Not Connected");}
          else{MessageBox.Show(e.Result);}
      };
      client.DoConnectAsync(Convert.ToInt32(whoid.Text),winToLoad.Text);
  }
  ```
- Console Application referring/calling WCF in Synchronous way on start.

  ```
  Console.WriteLine("Beginning...");
  Ref.WCFServicesX3Client client = new Ref.WCFServicesX3Client();
  client.DoConnect(1, "User 1");
  client.DoConnect(2, "User 2");
  client.DoConnect(3, "User 3");
  client.Close();
  ```

**Application Behavior/Issue**

WCF Hosted by Console Application is started and waiting...

I connect to the Silver Light Application hosted by IIS using Internet browner on Local address then press "Button" to call WCF --> return OK

Open a new web page on the same Local Address : the Silver light application is displayed then press "Button: to call WCF --> Return nothing - No error or Exception return by the call.

I can start several Client Console Application (Synchronous mode), the issue is not appearing.

**Question**

Does Asynchronous mode need to be manually closed (I though it was done automatically) ?

Is it a problem of IIS Configuration / Parametrization ?
If you have any idea where I should focus my test/search, your are welcome :).

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I didn't find the solution but a workaround based on following architecture : SL Client - WCF.Web hosted by IIS - WCF Services Hosted by Console Application. And now, I am investigating WCF RIA Services.